# Confusion of Properties, Data, and Computed Values when Working with Components (especially nested)

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am really confused how to pass down properties from a parent and update them in children then emit those changes all the way back up to the parent.  By reference it looks to work but from everything I read that is not the correct way to do it.

I have a parent component which "toggles" a create form.  A new instance of the artifact is created and passed into a "create" component which is used in other places.  The create component has some common properties but, through a slot, custom properties can be added at the parent level.

Within the ArtifactCreate component, it passes a "clone" of that prop to both the form and the custom properties.

I am trying to understand how to take the "prop" value, work with it internally, and then bubble up the final result to the ArtifactCreate component which in-turn bubbles that up to the parent.

The "child" components (ArtifactCreateForm and DatasetProperties) do not have any additional methods and are directly updating the prop reference passed in.  DatasetProperties can be used in other places as well.

In most cases, I have a "parent" that I want to handle the main interaction but need to pass some model down to one or more components, which in turn may pass that in its children.

The structure looks close to this:

```
Parent Component (somewhat like the controller handling main actions)
   |
   |--- View Component (takes in 'artifact' prop and passes it down)
            |
            |--- Child Component
                     |
                     |--- GrandChild 1..x
   |-----------------|--- GrandChild (through slot)
```

I am really confused on on the relationship between properties and data and/or computed values and how to correctly work with that data in the grandchildren.  I am fine with the concept of pass data down and emit events up and I seem to grasp how to do that with primitive properties but how can I do this with an object that has many properties?

***My questions are:***

1. What is the correct way to pass props and handle them inside the components (as a copy), then bubble that back up to the parent?
2. When bubbling the event from lower components is the only way to repeat it until it reaches the parent?
3. I am using "objects" as the prop/data not individual values.  The reference gets updated (which is a copy) then bubbled to the parent (as I want).  Is this the right way?

(FYI, coming from Java to Vue so this is a whole new world to me).

**Parent Component**

This is my entry into the create component.  It manages the instance (in this case a new one) and passes it down to the ArtifactCreate component which internally clones it.  The updated copy is bubbled back to here where it is saved.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <artifact-header/>
    <v-container fluid>
      <!-- List -->
      <reference-list
        :paths="paths"
        @open="load"/>
      <!-- Create Artifact -->
      <artifact-create
        :advanced="true"
        :artifact="newArtifact"
        :title="newTitle"
        @save="save">
        <template #default="{ model }">
          <dataset-properties :artifact="model"/>
        </template>
      </artifact-create>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

Supported by:

```js
 computed: {
    newArtifact: {
      get(): Dataset {
        return newDataset();
      }
    }
 },
  methods: {
    save(item: Dataset){
      this.$store.dispatch("saveDataset", item);
    },
```

**ArtifactCreate Component (child / container component)**

```html
<app-dialog
  :title="title"
  :visible="visible"
  @action="save"
  @close="close">
  <v-tabs v-if="advanced"
    v-model="tab"
    grow>
    <v-tab>Basic</v-tab>
    <v-tab>Advanced</v-tab>
    <!-- Basic Properties -->
    <v-tab-item :key="'Basic'">
      <artifact-create-form :artifact="internal"/>
    </v-tab-item>
    <!-- Advanced Properties -->
    <v-tab-item :key="'Advanced'">
      <slot :model="internal"/>
    </v-tab-item>
  </v-tabs>
  <!-- Basic Properties ONLY -->
  <artifact-create-form v-else 
    :artifact="internal"/>
</app-dialog>
```

And it is supported with:

```js
export default Vue.extend({
  name: "ArtifactCreate",
  props:{
    artifact: {
      type: Object as Prop<IArtifact>,
      default: {}
    },
  },
  computed:{
    internal: {
      get(): IArtifact {
        return clone(this.artifact);
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    save(item) {
      this.$emit('save', this.internal);
      this.visible = false;
    },
  },
});
```

**ArtifactCreateForm Component (child in ArtifactCreate)**

```html
<template>
  <v-form>
    <v-text-field
      v-model="artifact.name"
      label="Name*" 
      required>
    </v-text-field>
  </v-form>
</template>
```

Supported by:

```js
export default Vue.extend({
  name: "ArtifactCreateForm",
  props:{
    artifact: {
      type: Object as Prop<IArtifact>,
      default: {}
    },
  },
});
```

**DatasetProperties Component (child in ArtifactCreate / registered in parent through slot)**

```html
<template>
  <v-form>
    <v-text-field 
      v-model="artifact.source"
      label="Source">
    </v-text-field>
    <v-text-field 
      v-model="artifact.primaryKey"
      label="Primary Key">
    </v-text-field>
  </v-form>
</template>
```

Supported by:

```js
export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'DatasetProperties',
  props:{
    artifact: {
      type: Object as Prop<Dataset>,
      default: {}
    }
  },
})
```

I have Vuex in place and "could" use that but it seems like overkill for creating a new object?  But similar to how to work with data still trying to get where/when it is appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complex model and form handling is not straight forward and there are very few good examples how to handle complex forms with custom component v-model implementations especially if you want v-model on objects. I'll attempt to give my recommendations below.

> 1. What is the correct way to pass props and handle them inside the components (as a copy), then bubble that back up to the parent?

It depends, if like in your example at the parent level you want to pass an initial object value through a prop and happy to wait until a final event occurs e.g. `:artifact="newArtifact" @save="save"`, then that is the way to go. In other words, to me your Parent Component looks good.

However once you start working on child and lower components where you start working with the actual model properties via `v-model` it gets a bit more complex. See below.

> 2. When bubbling the event from lower components is the only way to repeat it until it reaches the parent?

As you pointed out in the original question, the "Vue way" way is -> data down and events up. In fact that is even how `v-model` work, remember `v-model="model"` is basically short for `:value="model" @input="model = $event"`. But this gets a little messy when the model is an object and as mentioned above, there are few good examples on how to handle custom component v-model with complex objects as models.
See 3 below.

> 3. I am using "objects" as the prop/data not individual values. The reference gets updated (which is a copy) then bubbled to the parent (as I want). Is this the right way?

Using data updates by reference is not considered best practice for the reasons pointed out in @bviala answer. It also breaks the data down events up approach. Ideally, your child components `ArtifactCreateForm` and `DatasetProperties` should implement v-model functionality. As mentioned, implementing v-model in your custom component especially on objects is not as clean as you would hope. But you can implement helper functions to make it a bit easier.

For example, implementing v-model on your `ArtifactCreateForm` component, it would look like this:

```
<template>
  <v-form>
    <v-text-field
      :value="value.name"
      @input="update(m => (m.name = $event))
      label="Name*" 
      required>
    </v-text-field>
    <v-text-field
      :value="value.description"
      @input="update(m => (m.description = $event))
      label="Description" 
      required>
    </v-text-field>
  </v-form>
</template>


export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'ArtifactCreateForm',
  props:{
    value: {
      type: Object as Prop<IArtifact>
    }
  },
  methods: {
    update(cb: (m: IArtifact) => void) {
      const model = clone(this.value);
      cb(model);
      this.$emit("input", model);
    }
  }
})
```

And you would use this as:

```
<app-dialog
  :title="title"
  :visible="visible"
  @action="save"
  @close="close">

  <artifact-create-form v-model="internal"/>

</app-dialog>
```

For reference the following blog post helped me a lot on how to implement v-model with objects on custom components: https://simonkollross.de/posts/vuejs-using-v-model-with-objects-for-custom-components

Comment: Hah, I am literally on that site right now as well!  This seems to be the approach I want though a lot more work than I expected originally.

Comment: I am still trying to implement the solution, the answer above makes sense and is what I am trying to do so I am optimistic this is the answer (it sort of looks like it works so far for what I have done).

Comment: I use something similar in my project at the moment and it works great. Unfortunately I haven't had the need to implement it through slots like your `DatasetProperties` use case, but I suspect it wouldn't be a problem. Feel free to post an update if anything is unclear.

Comment: Seems to work good and according to the vue tools in chrome doing what I would expect.  The only thing I note is that I had to create a 'computed' property and then set my v-model to that or I got an "avoid mutating props" error.  I'll update my question with what I did after I play around with a little bit.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, i think it "clicked" for me now!  So, I initialize a data property, internal, with the prop.  Pass that as the v-model into the children components.  The children emit the changes back up.  Because the parent has the v-model the two-way binding kicks in and updates the data property.  That updated property is then what i will emit through save.

Comment: Is it a correct assumption that as the parent "internal" in data is getting updated that in-turn those changes are pushed down through the properties so that props in the children reflects those changes?  Just making sure I am not caught in the "reference" changes again...

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct on both comments. Because the only data that gets updated is the parent internal model, it will always get pushed down to the other child components via the vmodel prop. And since the child references this directly via :value and never changes it directly, only indirectly through the input event, you get proper two way binding.

Comment: The key is that in the child where you work with v-text-field or other form fields, you use :value and @input with emit so that the child never directly updates the main model, but only through the input event emitted, so the value prop in the child is immutable and you wont get that vue error where vue complaints about changing a prop value directly

Comment: Sorry I meant to say in the child you use :value and @input and not :value and `@update`. I edited my comment above to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the correct way to pass props and handle them inside the components (as a copy), then bubble that back up to the parent?

**As a copy**, like you did in `ArtifactCreate` : Clone the prop, mutate it however you want, send it to the parent with an event if needed.

But if your child component doesn't need to have its own internal value, you shouldn't clone the prop, but rather just emit events and let the parent handle the mutation. It would look like this in the child:

```
<v-text-field 
  :value="artifact.source"
  label="Source"
  @input="$emit('updateSource', $event)"
>
```

What's weird in your example is that your child component clones data that the parent just created. Couldn't the child be the one in charge of calling `newDataset()`?

> When bubbling the event from lower components is the only way to repeat it until it reaches the parent?

Yes, the only **proper** way (see next answer)

> I am using "objects" as the prop/data not individual values. The reference gets updated (which is a copy) then bubbled to the parent (as I want). Is this the right way?

What you did in `ArtifactCreateForm`  `DatasetProperties` works but is considered an anti-pattern. The reason being that the data lives in the parent component and is mutated by the child, **with the source of the mutation being unknown by the parent**. It can lead to maintenance issues if your component hierarchy becomes complex. The correct way is to send events.

That's why in my opinion, you should split your components mindfully: Do you really have reusability potential for `ArtifactCreateForm` and `DatasetProperties` ? If not, you can make your life easier by sticking to a single `ArtifactCreate` component.

Comment: Yes, there are many artifacts, each with base and customized with advanced properties so there is a need for those components because they are used in multiple places, i can rollup the create form right into the create. I can move where the clone happens, idea was to send the raw data to the component to clone then pass down (because I may reset the changes before bubbling backup and the component seemed like the responsible place to handle that).  So, based answer, I need to bubble up each property as an event?  When there are more than a few properties that seems like a lot of effort.

Comment: FYI @BVialia, thanks for the answer.  That actually did help clarify the usage better.  I can see how to use events at the property (name, source, etc.) level but in this case I dont really want those changes immediately but instead, before saving, after they are all there and ready. So, how can I collect all the changes in the "CreateComponent" then when I click save pass them all over at once to the parent to be handled?